# iOS Audio Service : Read & write audio files

Tags: ios

guys.

I'm working on some audio services on iOS.

I trying to search any examples or tutorials about

how audio service or stream can read a existing audio file than

process something like filter, than write another file.

Is there any body who can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Dirac3LE](http://dirac.dspdimension.com/Dirac3_Technology_Home_Page/Dirac3_Technology.html) (by Stephan M. Bernsee) is a great library for this job.

There are examples and manual included in the download.

It is particulary inteded for time and pitch manipulation
but in your case you'll be interested in its `EAFRead` and `EAFWrite`
classes.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get familiar with the lower level library that you can also use for microphone input/sound output, and that you can get raw samples into and out of, I would suggest taking a look at [Audio Queue Services](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/MusicAudio/Conceptual/AudioQueueProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html).

I used it in my side project to get audio from the microphone, and I also wrote some code you might find useful to do fast vectorized, FFT based FIR filtering on input audio. You can find the code here https://github.com/jamescarlson/FreeAPRS

Comment: Just realized this post is 4 years old, oops! Hope someone finds this useful though.